# Как закрывать процессы приложений и сервисов?

Tags: android

Заметил такую странную вещь: после закрытия приложения ("смахивания" пальцем в диспетчере задач) и после остановки сервиса методом `stopService` — процессы приложений и сервисов висят в *Android Device Monitor*. По всей видимости, из-за этого у меня и возникают проблемы, потому что и `Application` приложения не закрываются. Так почему же приложения и сервисы висят в фоне, и как их программно "убивать"?

Comment: @metalurgus, у меня возникает проблема из-за не закрытия приложения. Но да ладно, нельзя — значит нельзя. Добавьте в ответ.

Comment: Опишите проблему в новом вопросе. Уверен, для нее тоже есть решение.

Comment: @metalurgus, уже...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой ответ - никак. Это не в вашей компетенции.
Когда и как именно убивать процессы - решает система. Вам же нужно организовать свое приложение так, чтобы в нем не возникало проблем при повторном открытии/восстановлении, и т. п.